Is the adjunction between spaces and chain complexes monadic?
Consider the adjunction of $\infty$-categories $\mathbb{Z}[-]: \mathcal{Spaces} \rightleftarrows \text{Ch}_{\ge 0}(\mathbb{Z}): |-|$ where the left adjoint takes a space to its singular chain complex over $\mathbb{Z}$. Is this adjunction monadic? By Barr-Beck-Lurie, this would be equivalent to the right adjoint $|-|$ preserving $|-|$-split geometric realizations. I've been unable to come up with a nice counterexample or proof, and no references of any sort, but I have to imagine someone else has given this some thought.

Do you mean the 1-category $\operatorname{Ch}{\ge0}(\mathbb Z)$ of $\mathbb N$-graded chain complexes, but not the connective derived category $\mathcal D{\ge0}(\mathbb Z)$? Then this seems to be false: the right adjoint $\operatorname{Ch}_{\ge0}(\mathbb Z)\to\operatorname{An}$ does not seem to be conservative.

@Z.M I mean the $\infty$-category of $\mathbb{N}$-graded chain complexes up to quasi-isomorphism - apologies if I used implicitly $1$-categorical notation.

Every 1-category is an $\infty$-category. There is a real issue: it makes sense to talk about chain complexes in an additive ($\infty$-)category. In particular, there is a notion of chain complexes of spectra (which is rougly equivalent to completely filtered spectra), and Lurie has a version of Dold–Kan correspondence for stable $\infty$-categories (which is further generalized to weakly idempotent additive $\infty$-categories by Tashi Walde). Thus denoting the derived category by "chain complexes" is very misleading.

This answer assumes that $\def\Ch{{\sf Ch}}\def\Z{{\bf Z}}\Ch_{≥0}(\Z)$ refers to the derived ∞-category of chain complexes, i.e., with quasi-isomorphisms inverted up to a homotopy.
Recall that the right adjoint to $\def\sSet{{\sf sSet}}\def\N{{\sf N}}\N\Z[-]\colon\sSet→\Ch_{≥0}$ can be computed as $UΓ$, where $\def\sAb{{\sf sAb}}Γ\colon\Ch_{≥0}(\Z)→\sAb$ is the Dold–Kan functor and $U\colon\sAb→\sSet$ is the forgetful functor.
The functor $Γ$ is an equivalence of ∞-categories, so it suffices to establish that $U\colon\sAb→\sSet$ is a monadic functor.
The ∞-category $\sAb$ of simplicial abelian groups is the ∞-category of algebras over the algebraic theory of abelian groups.  Every ∞-category of algebras over an algebraic theory is monadic over the ∞-category of spaces, which concludes the proof.

Thank you! For anyone else who is looking for a reference, https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.02991v1 (Example 2.5).
